# Matrix element of the currents associated with the broken generators between the vacuum and Goldstone's bosons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, goldstone-mode

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $L^i$ the generators of this group. Suppose we have  $L^{j}|0\rangle \neq 0$ where $|0\rangle \neq 0$ denotes the vacuum. If $G$ is associated with a symmetry of the Lagrangian $L$  according to Noether's theorem we have a set of conserved  currents $J_i^
\mu$.

According to Goldstone's theorem   $L^{j}|0\rangle \neq 0$ implies that we have $j$th massless boson  $|p,j\rangle $.

Now in this article [Exact and Broken Symmetries in Particle Physics](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0002225) by Peccei they are claiming that we   should have
$$
\left\langle 0\left|J_{i}^{\mu}(0)\right| p , j\right\rangle=i f_{j} \delta_{i j} p^{\mu}\tag{49}
$$
where $f_{j}$ are some non-vanishing constants.

Why this last expression is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$
\left\langle 0\left|J_{i}^{\mu}(0)\right| p , j\right\rangle=:F^\mu_{ij}(p)
$$

The only object with a $\mu$ index is $p$ itself, so by Lorentz invariance $F^\mu_{ij}(p)=p^\mu F_{ij}(p^2)$ for some scalar function $F$. But $p^2=m^2$ is just a constant, so $F_{ij}(p^2)=f_{ij}$ for some numbers $f_{ij}$:
$$
\left\langle 0\left|J_{i}^{\mu}(0)\right| p , j\right\rangle=p^\mu f_{ij}
$$

Finally, diagonalize $f_{ij}$ to get the expression in the OP.

See also §19 in ref.1.

**References.**

1. Weinberg S., *Quantum theory of fields*, Vol.2. Modern Applications.